# error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token

Tags: c

I've got this stupid little problem I can't solve...

```
exer3.c: In function ‘shm_pipe_pipe’:
exer3.c:69:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
exer3.c:69:39: error: too few arguments to function ‘shmget’
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys/shm.h:54:12: note: declared here
```

line's 69 surroundings:

```
pipes_array[i].m_key = 1;
key = i;

pipes_array[i].m_shmid = shmget(key, PIPE_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600); //69

if (pipes_array[i].m_shmid < 0) {
    perror("Error");
    return -1;
}
```

then:

```
exer3.c: In function ‘shm_pipe_read’:
exer3.c:111:60: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

line's 111 surroundings:

```
    current_bytes_to_read = total_bytes_to_read <= pipes_array[i].m_bytes_in_pipe ? total_bytes_to_read : pipes_array[i].m_bytes_in_pipe;

    //reading the information
    if ((pipes_array[i].m_roffset + current_bytes_to_read) < PIPE_SIZE) { //111
        memcpy(buf + offset, tbuffer + pipes_array[i].m_roffset, current_bytes_to_read);
```

then:
    exer3.c: In function ‘shm_pipe_write’:
    exer3.c:153:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token

line's 153 surroundings:

```
while (total_bytes_to_write != 0) {
    if (pipes_array[i].m_bytes_in_pipe == PIPE_SIZE) { //153


make: *** [exer3.o] Error 1
```

Can someone please help me with that? thanks!

Comment: Show the definition of PIPE_SIZE please, then remove the trailing semi-colon on it.

Comment: just fyi, @hudac. the homework tag has been deprecated and should no longer be used. I removed it from your question. please remember this with future question. it would be much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your PIPE_SIZE macro probably looks like this:

```
#define PIPE_SIZE   100;
```

throw out the semi-colon (and add some parens if they aren't there).

Comment: How do you know it's 100?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't, but I'm fairly confident of that semi-colon. Hopefully the OP connects the dots.

Comment: Yes, I was just kidding. I'm pretty confident you're right too, I wouldn't have upvoted otherwise ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer I kinda knew you were, but you bring up a very good point. I hope the OP keeps his PIPE_SIZE and just throws out the semi-colon. Of course, I'd laugh my ass off if changing it to one hundred magically fixed some other bug because the original value was undersized. *that* would be hysterical.